# Shooting script for playing with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

3D game

I need to improve the code for firing **in Unity in C#** so that the weapon shoots not only along one trajectory, since the bullet flies along z and does not change the trajectory when turning.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShotToClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Bullet;
    public float Power;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject b = Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            b.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.forward * Power, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }  
}
```

I am a beginner and I try to learn by creating projects, I hope for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this. use the direction from the transform

```cs
GameObject b = Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
b.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward) * Power, ForceMode.Impulse);
```